# How to keep SVG the same size during browser zoom in/out

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a landing page with an SVG image as the background.  I'd like to lock its size in place so if the browser is zoomed in or out it doesn't change.  It looks crappy zoomed out.k

Here's an svg example from Twitter of the functionality I'm talking about.  If you open this svg code in a browser, the twitter bird doesn't change size if you command&+/- and zoom out.

```html
<svg class="twitterIcon-bird" viewBox="0 0 1208 982" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 45.2 (43514) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>bird</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Final-Horizon" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" transform="translate(-286.000000, -117.000000)" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#1B95E0">
            <path d="M1493.75308,233.195911 C1449.31783,252.922544 1401.56126,266.207828 1351.43951,272.19627 C1402.61804,241.549536 1441.92034,192.987798 1460.3889,135.116296 C1412.53168,163.498493 1359.49119,184.130942 1303.02874,195.252335 C1257.88897,147.093181 1193.42514,117 1122.16771,117 C962.190754,117 844.636121,266.258151 880.768067,421.202806 C674.896491,410.886582 492.324484,312.253414 370.089808,162.341063 C305.17308,273.705962 336.423691,419.391176 446.731805,493.16476 C406.171431,491.856361 367.925917,480.734968 334.561738,462.165765 C331.844294,576.95263 414.122472,684.342008 533.287442,708.245454 C498.413572,717.706186 460.218381,719.9204 421.368991,712.47259 C452.871217,810.904465 544.358512,882.514158 652.854997,884.52708 C548.686294,966.201382 417.443793,1002.68559 286,987.186091 C395.653915,1057.48739 525.940278,1098.50067 665.838342,1098.50067 C1125.89162,1098.50067 1385.81015,709.956437 1370.10936,361.469352 C1418.52012,326.494836 1460.53987,282.864756 1493.75308,233.195911 Z" id="bird"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here's my image's svg info that I'd like to behave similarly.  You might need to copy and paste this into a file and view in a browser.  It's a curved image with multiple layers.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="18.4268546%" y1="27.9722359%" x2="82.7977891%" y2="77.3056038%" id="linearGradient-1">
            <stop stop-color="#1E87F0" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#1E3E5C" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="18.4268546%" y1="28.295015%" x2="82.7977891%" y2="76.9054869%" id="linearGradient-2">
            <stop stop-color="#1E87F0" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#1E3E5C" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <path d="M0.882548395,15.7999936 L1.20671504,819.366633 C336.735572,860.919994 594.34158,794.683198 774.024741,620.656245 C932.62388,467.049615 996.276998,527.683301 1151.1184,531.228148 C1305.9598,534.772995 1508.44994,684.094916 1631.51564,783.962916 C1713.55944,850.541583 1650.01507,594.487275 1440.88255,15.7999936 L0.882548395,15.7999936 Z" id="path-3"></path>
        <linearGradient x1="10.0537047%" y1="28.3217065%" x2="117.215768%" y2="106.344139%" id="linearGradient-5">
            <stop stop-color="#1E87F0" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#1E3E5C" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <path d="M12.04293,25 L6.90201099,735.285212 C159.518234,768.654318 306.462792,773.140482 447.735683,748.743705 C773.312884,692.518943 874.037615,533.915834 1153.33439,533.901355 C1339.53225,533.891702 1497.8173,596.686321 1628.18954,722.285212 L1464.16913,25 L12.04293,25 Z" id="path-6"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Landing-page" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Landing-page---v2">
            <g id="Bitmap" transform="translate(-12.000000, -25.000000)">
                <path d="M60.8501735,0.107667822 L60.8501735,687.900102 C293.733255,762.384295 480.221381,787.428003 620.314551,763.031226 C943.172971,706.806464 1004.024,482.419288 1280.98847,482.404809 C1557.95294,482.39033 1520.08109,690.064545 1643.14678,789.932545 C1725.19058,856.511212 1677.75838,593.236253 1500.85017,0.107667822 L60.8501735,0.107667822 Z" id="Mask-Copy" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="0.12"></path>
                <mask id="mask-4" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                </mask>
                <use id="Mask-Copy-2" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="0.12" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <mask id="mask-7" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                </mask>
                <use id="Mask" fill="url(#linearGradient-5)" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

What changes can I make to my svg file to make it behave like the twitter svg?

Comment: If you double the numbers in `viewBox` in your twitter bird i.e. `<svg class="twitterIcon-bird" viewBox="0 0 2416 1964" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` you get half the size, does that give you some clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the `viewBox`, now I leave it to you to put your markup in that `viewbox` - since it is off center.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="18.4268546%" y1="27.9722359%" x2="82.7977891%" y2="77.3056038%" id="linearGradient-1">
            <stop stop-color="#1E87F0" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#1E3E5C" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="18.4268546%" y1="28.295015%" x2="82.7977891%" y2="76.9054869%" id="linearGradient-2">
            <stop stop-color="#1E87F0" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#1E3E5C" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <path d="M0.882548395,15.7999936 L1.20671504,819.366633 C336.735572,860.919994 594.34158,794.683198 774.024741,620.656245 C932.62388,467.049615 996.276998,527.683301 1151.1184,531.228148 C1305.9598,534.772995 1508.44994,684.094916 1631.51564,783.962916 C1713.55944,850.541583 1650.01507,594.487275 1440.88255,15.7999936 L0.882548395,15.7999936 Z" id="path-3"></path>
        <linearGradient x1="10.0537047%" y1="28.3217065%" x2="117.215768%" y2="106.344139%" id="linearGradient-5">
            <stop stop-color="#1E87F0" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#1E3E5C" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <path d="M12.04293,25 L6.90201099,735.285212 C159.518234,768.654318 306.462792,773.140482 447.735683,748.743705 C773.312884,692.518943 874.037615,533.915834 1153.33439,533.901355 C1339.53225,533.891702 1497.8173,596.686321 1628.18954,722.285212 L1464.16913,25 L12.04293,25 Z" id="path-6"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Landing-page" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Landing-page---v2">
            <g id="Bitmap" transform="translate(-12.000000, -25.000000)">
                <path d="M60.8501735,0.107667822 L60.8501735,687.900102 C293.733255,762.384295 480.221381,787.428003 620.314551,763.031226 C943.172971,706.806464 1004.024,482.419288 1280.98847,482.404809 C1557.95294,482.39033 1520.08109,690.064545 1643.14678,789.932545 C1725.19058,856.511212 1677.75838,593.236253 1500.85017,0.107667822 L60.8501735,0.107667822 Z" id="Mask-Copy" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="0.12"></path>
                <mask id="mask-4" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                </mask>
                <use id="Mask-Copy-2" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="0.12" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <mask id="mask-7" fill="white">
                    <use xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                </mask>
                <use id="Mask" fill="url(#linearGradient-5)" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks.  how do I change its size to make it larger and still keep it fixed in size during zoom?

Comment: I think you have to re-draw it to the size you want.  If you give it a width and height, it would then change size on zoom i.e. `width="100em" height="100em"` which is not what you indicate you want

Comment: Got it.  I ended up stretching it out instead of redrawing it and it looks fine on 80% zoom out now, which is plenty.  Thanks!