# how to make certain svg/image sub-element stay same size & position when zooming with panzoom library

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, svg

I am using this javascript library for zooming in a map of a country which is an svg file:
https://timmywil.com/panzoom/

I have an SVG `<image>` tag in the svg map, which is actually the image of a pin. Note this is different from the HTML `<img>` tag.

Here is the relevant code, in assets/id1.svg. The values are hardcoded as of now.

```
<circle fill="red" class="geo-champ-map-area cls-3" id="Großglockner"
          cx="333.71" cy="304.14" r="10"/>
<image
    id="pin" x="303.71" y="244.14" href="assets/pin.png" width="60" height="60"/>
```

Obviously when zooming in, the size of the svg increases, and obviously the pin-`<image>` is part of the `<svg>`, thus it also increases in size.

When zooming in, I want this `<image>`-pin to:

1. stay at the same x/y coordinate (this works by default, doesn't require any code)
2. stay the same size (this is hard)

For an example, I want it to behave the same as the red google maps pins.
However google maps is a very different story, since they don't use svg for their maps.

I have read other posts:
[SVG prevent scaling when zooming page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251136/svg-prevent-scaling-when-zooming-page)
[How to keep SVG the same size during browser zoom in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316723/how-to-keep-svg-the-same-size-during-browser-zoom-in-out)

But they didn't help for obvious reasons, since the use case is not with the svg panzoom library. Viewport is not a solution here I think.

Here is a minimal reproducible example page where you can see what I am trying.
https://github.com/folsze/pin-panzoom

Here when zooming in, the red pin should stay the same size and stay over the exact same dot (I want to replace all white dots with red pins)
[image]

GPT-4 suggested I use the `updatePinScale()` method.
If you comment-in the usage of the `updatePinScale()` method, you will see that the pin now actually stays the same size. But now it is dragged all the way to the right-bottom of the screen.

Here is the code:

```
  private updatePinScale() {
    console.log('AAA');
    // Calculate the inverse scale based on the current zoom scale
    const inverseScale = 1 / this.panzoom.getScale();

    const pin = document.getElementById('pin')!;
    const circle = document.getElementById('Großglockner')!;

    // Get the circle center coordinates and pin dimensions
    const circleCenterX = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cx')!);
    const circleCenterY = parseFloat(circle.getAttribute('cy')!);
    const pinWidth = parseFloat(pin.getAttribute('width')!);
    const pinHeight = parseFloat(pin.getAttribute('height')!);

    // Calculate the adjusted pin position based on the circle's position and pin dimensions
    const adjustedPinX = circleCenterX - pinWidth / 2 * inverseScale;
    const adjustedPinY = circleCenterY - pinHeight * inverseScale;

    // Set the pin's scale transform and adjusted position
    pin.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${adjustedPinX}, ${adjustedPinY}) scale(${inverseScale})`);
  }
```

Additional notes:

- I really do not care about the way this is done. So workarounds are welcome. E.g. use `<img>` instead of `<image>`. Or use `<svg>` instead of `<image>`. I do not have to stick to a certain narrow solution space.
- How to run the project: just type `ionic serve`. Or `npm start`

Comment: Please include relevant code in  your question, not on an external site (this is so your question can remain useful for future readers). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example